# Emergency: Channel entries tags stopped working on a live site: Please Help!

Tags: channel-entries

I have just received a very unusual support request:

All of the content on a live website is no longer displayed on the front end of my clients site. All content is still accessible via control panel.

Basically every instance of Channel:entries isn't working, neither are any structure tags, low event tags, low search results tags- basically if it extends channel entries its stopped working.

I have setup a test template with the simplest of channel entries tags on there, but no matter which channel/entry I try to pull I keep getting the contents of my no_results conditional. As an a-side, Channel:categories tag works fine.
It seems to me that the entries method of the channel module has died somehow- the only changes that have happened on this site in weeks have been content based.

Has anyone experienced this issue before? or have any pointers on how to resolve this- I've been looking at this all morning and can't event find anyone reporting a similar issue in the past (which is very disconcerting)

Thanks in advance!

ISSUE RESOLVED:
It turns out that one of my clients employees had somehow applied a custom status to all entries, even those that existed in channels without the custom statuses applied.
So the pages, news, events channels etc all returned zero results as they didn't have the matching status!

Comment: We need some details to possibly help: What version of EE? version of PHP? What add-ons are installed? Their versions? Any errors when you turn on debugging in /index.php? What's your default home template look like?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Stephen. Luckily we managed to figure this out (with a Fresh pair of eyeballs courtesy of Carl Crawley):

It turns out that one of my clients employees had somehow applied a custom status to all entries, even those that existed in channels without the custom statuses applied.
So the pages, news, events channels etc all returned zero results as they didn't have the matching status!

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. Could you post your finding as an answer below for future googlers?

Comment: Neil, please post your solution as an answer below and accept your answer as correct.

Comment: Sorry guys still getting used to SE etiquette- see below for solution to the problem

Comment: I am also facing the same issue on my live site today and i am not sure why it suddenly stopped working. Also i have verified that there is no custom statuses existing on live site. Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: @NikhilKhurana If you have the same issue, but this solution does not work, please post a separate question, including as much detail as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISSUE RESOLVED: It turns out that one of my clients employees had somehow applied a custom status to all entries, even those that existed in channels without the custom statuses applied. So the pages, news, events channels etc all returned zero results as they didn't have the matching status!

This was resolved by setting all entries back to the relevant entry statuses to open.